# Conditional Formatting replaced with Permanent Formatting (Excel Calendar)

Tags: excel, calendar, formatting, format, conditional-statements

I am trying to take an Excel Vacation Calendar I created for my job which requires a shit-ton of Conditional Formats to operate, to remove the Conditional Formatting without removing or changing how he cells appear. I want the Conditional Formatting to be made the 'Normal' Formatting. I have tried many solutions to this over the last several months. I'm not sure how to demonstrate what I have tried so I will likely just link to the pages that hold the formulas.

Formula 1:
https://excel.tips.net/T001947_Removing_Conditional_Formats_but_Not_the_Effects.html

This one breaks here:
Case xlExpression
If Application.Evaluate(FC.Formula1) Then
ActiveCondition = ndx
Exit Function
End If
in the third segment. If removed it completes but the conditional formatting remains, and I see no other changes except some minor discoloration:

Formula 2:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3686-excel-remove-conditional-formatting-but-keep-format.html

This one does the job but for some reason the text color reverts to default black instead of the color the Conditional Formatting had. This is actually the same problem I had with 2 other attempts. The first segment does maintain the text color but everywhere else it loses it.

Formula 3:
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-conditional-formatting-into-standard-one.284013/

This one functioned but for some reason it seemed to invert the condition's or something. This ended with every Tuesday highlighted, every Friday highlighted, and almost every day with an orange bar indicating no work.

[Month of February With All Color created by Conditional Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwyRb.png) As you can see this is a complicated mess. I'm using all sorts of formula and basing colors on the calendar off of different pages that tell you which days off you have and everything. These Conditional Formula's and in line formulas take up a huge amount of data. At the end of each year I want to be able to wipe all the formulas and conditions without changing how it looks. I could manually go through and format each cell then delete all 2108 Conditional Formats for the days of the year, and the 240 for the totals for vacation and sick days, but that defeats the purpose. Please help, I am literally losing my mind trying out anything to get this to work.

I would attach a copy of my file so you could actually look at how this thing works if I could, If it would help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "*I want the Conditional Formatting to be made the 'Normal' Formatting.*"  **Normal** with regard to formatting refers to a Style. AFAIK, a Style cannot contain complicated conditions. If that's what you really want, you'll need VBA.

Comment: If you are concerned about code not working, you should show us how you have tried to get it to work. But you also need to understand what the code you are using is doing. The code (at least on the extendoffice site) is setting the various parameters to be the same as what is being displayed. Since you say your problem is that the font color property isn't correct, perhaps you should examine the code to see what it is doing with regard to that property, and fix that.